# Insert into Many2many Odoo (former OpenERP)

Tags: insert, many-to-many, odoo

I'm trying to insert values into a `Many2many` or `One2many` relation table field in Odoo (former OpenERP). Do you have any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Here's an example from the [stock module](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/%7Eopenerp/openobject-addons/5.0/view/2930/stock/stock.py#L834):

```
invoice_line_id = invoice_line_obj.create(cursor, user, {
    'name': name,
    'origin': origin,
    'invoice_id': invoice_id,
    'uos_id': uos_id,
    'product_id': move_line.product_id.id,
    'account_id': account_id,
    'price_unit': price_unit,
    'discount': discount,
    'quantity': move_line.product_uos_qty or move_line.product_qty,
    'invoice_line_tax_id': [(6, 0, tax_ids)],
    'account_analytic_id': account_analytic_id,
    }, context=context)
self._invoice_line_hook(cursor, user, move_line, invoice_line_id)
```

The `invoice_line_tax_id` field is a many-to-many relationship, and the `(6, 0, tax_ids)` means to replace any existing records with those in `tax_ids`. Because you're calling `create()`, there's nothing to replace.

A full list of options is in the [documentation for the osv class](http://doc.openerp.com/v6.0/developer/2_5_Objects_Fields_Methods/methods.html#osv.osv.osv.write).

> For a many2many field, a list of tuples is expected. Here is the list of tuple that are accepted, with the corresponding semantics
>
> `(0, 0,  { values })`    link to a new record that needs to be created with the given values dictionary
>
> `(1, ID, { values })`    update the linked record with id = ID (write *values* on it)
>
> `(2, ID)`                remove and delete the linked record with id = ID (calls unlink on ID, that will delete the object completely, and the link to it as well)
>
> `(3, ID)`                cut the link to the linked record with id = ID (delete the relationship between the two objects but does not delete the target object itself)
>
> `(4, ID)`                link to existing record with id = ID (adds a relationship)
>
> `(5)`                    unlink all (like using (3,ID) for all linked records)
>
> `(6, 0, [IDs])`          replace the list of linked IDs (like using (5) then (4,ID) for each ID in the list of IDs)

Comment: But i don't know the object name of the many2many rel table... That means i can view that two-col-table in database, but i don't know how to get it through http.request.registry[]. Do you know how?

Answer (score 8):

```
def list_customers(self, cr, uid, ids, context):
    sale_obj = self.pool.get('sale.order')
    for sale in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context):
        sale_ids = sale_obj.search(cr, uid, [('div_code_id','=',sale.div_code_id.id),('project_user','=',sale.project_id.id),('tower_id','=',sale.tower_id.id)])
        ids_cus = []
        for cus in sale_obj.browse(cr, uid, sale_ids, context):
            if cus.partner_id.id not in ids_cus:
                ids_cus.append(cus.partner_id.id)
        self.write(cr, uid, ids, {'state_readonly':'listed','customer_ids': [(6, 0, ids_cus)]})
    return True
```

You can insert values into a many-to-many relation table in OpenERP, please look at above example

Answer (score 3):

When we create the many2many field then we used this syntax:

```
'field_name':fields.many2many('Module_name','relation_name','self_id','module_name_id','string',
```

Now u need to insert into this relation by execute queries like:

```
 $ cr.execute('insert into relation_name (self_id,module_name_id) values(%s,%s)',(first_value,second_value)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put your many2many field in view (xml file) and after running your module you can see many2many field to insert records in your gui

Comment: can we add list to vals parameter in 'create(self, cr, user, vals, context=None):' for insert multiple records at once.?

Answer (score 0):

### For adding data in Many2many field:

```
self.m2m_field = [(4, self.project_id.id)]
```

### For adding data in one2many field:

```
#Create list

data_list = []

#Adding data in list:

data_list.append((0, 0, {
    'user_id': self.user_id.id,
    'note': self.note,
    'create_date': self.create_date
}))

#Assign list to one2many field:

self.log_id = data_list
```