# Automated Action assign spesific tag_ids

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-12

I wanna add specific tag on `tag_ids` on `ir.attachment` with an Automated Action:

**Code:**

```
if record:
  if record.res_name and record.res_model_name == 'Task':
    key,name = record.res_name.split(" - ")
    rec =  env['project.task'].search([('key','=',key)])
    name_of_task = rec.key +" - " +rec.name
    if rec.x_studio_parent_project.x_assign_folder:  
      if rec.x_studio_level == "IMPLEMENTER":
        record._cr.execute("UPDATE ir_attachment SET folder_id = %s WHERE res_name= %s and res_model_name = 'Task'""",(rec.x_studio_parent_project.x_assign_folder.id, name_of_task))
      elif rec.x_studio_level == "SUPERVISOR":
        record._cr.execute("UPDATE ir_attachment SET folder_id = %s WHERE res_name= %s and res_model_name = 'Task'""",(rec.x_studio_parent_project.x_assign_folder.id, name_of_task))
    if rec.project_id.x_assign_folder:  
      if rec.x_studio_level == "INTERNAL CUSTOMER":
        record._cr.execute("UPDATE ir_attachment SET folder_id = %s WHERE res_name= %s and res_model_name = 'Task'""",(rec.project_id.x_assign_folder.id, name_of_task))
```

The code above is working but i wanna also change the tag id with specific `document.facet` id.

[image]

Tags = `tag_ids: Many2many field`

**I tried:**

`record.write({'tag_ids':[66]})`

`record.write({'tag_ids':[(66)]})`

`record.tag_ids = [(66)]`

`record.tag_ids = [66]`

`record.tag_ids = 66`

But none of them working any solution? Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [insert into many2many odoo (former openerp)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9377402/insert-into-many2many-odoo-former-openerp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On **Many2many** field, you can do like this,

```
record.write({'tag_ids':[(6, 0, [ID])]})
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

For a **many2many** field, a list of **tuples** is expected. Following are the list of how to pass tuples.

> (0, 0,  { values }) link to a new record that needs to be created with
>   the given values dictionary
>
> (1, ID, { values }) update the linked record with id = ID (write
>   values on it)
>
> (2, ID) remove and delete the linked record with id = ID (calls unlink
>   on ID, that will delete the object completely, and the link to it as
>   well)
>
> (3, ID) cut the link to the linked record with id = ID (delete the
>   relationship between the two objects but does not delete the target
>   object itself)
>
> (4, ID) link to existing record with id = ID (adds a relationship)
>
> (5) unlink all (like using (3,ID) for all linked records)
>
> (6, 0, [IDs]) replace the list of linked IDs (like using (5) then
>   (4,ID) for each ID in the list of IDs)